# Magento/PHP - How to get number of all members in a customer group

Tags: php, magento

I am working on a custom magento extension.

I've made a selection menu with all customer groups, here is the code of it:

```
$CustomerGroups = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/group_collection')->toOptionArray();

$CustomerGroups = array_merge(array('' => ''), $CustomerGroups);

$fieldset->addField('customergroups', 'select',
        array(
            'name'      => 'customergroups',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('User Group'),
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
            'values'    => $CustomerGroups
        )
    );
```

Here is the result:

[image]

As you can see the results are like this:

- not logged in
- General
- Wholesale
- Retailer

What i want is simply to add the number of members in every customer group, for example `General - (125 members)`.

Let me give you an example of what i want to achieve but don't know how in image:

[image]

Can you please help me out achieve that ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you donot want to use a direct MySQL Query on database then you can try this:

```
$customerCollectionSize = array();
$customerGroups         = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->getCollection();

foreach($customerGroups as $customerGroup) {
  $customerGroupId    = $customerGroup->getId();
  $customerCollection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('group_id', $customerGroupId);

        $customerCollectionSize[$customerGroupId] = $customerCollection->getSize(); 
}
```

Now in this array $customerCollectionSize you will have total no. of customers corresponding to the customer group id.

If you want to use direct MySQL Query then try as @tom-lankhorst suggested above:

```
SELECT `group_id`, count(*) AS `count` FROM `customer_entity` GROUP BY `group_id`
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

This query should do the job:

`` SELECT `group_id`, count(*) AS `count` FROM `customer_entity` GROUP BY `group_id` ``

Answer (score -1):

Group by Customer Group name:

```
  SELECT g.customer_group_code, count(e.entity_id) AS `count` FROM `customer_entity` AS e
    JOIN customer_group AS g on g.customer_group_id = e.group_id
    GROUP BY 1
```